# Unable to append the right values into drop down list for same row using Angular 7

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material

I am displaying the drop down list inside table rows but unable to append the right array values into for same row. I am providing my code below.

```
<button mat-button (click)="openDialog('Add',{})" mat-flat-button color="primary">Add Row</button>
<div class="clear"></div>
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="my-table mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">
      <mat-select placeholder="Select Option" aria-label="Select Option"
        (selectionChange)="onOptionTypeSelectionChanged($event,i)" formControlName="option" class="example-margin"
        [(ngModel)]="element.Name">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let s of option" [value]="s">
          <span *ngIf="!s">
          </span>
          <span *ngIf="s">
            {{s}}
          </span>
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Value column -->

  <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Values </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">
      <mat-select placeholder="Select Value" aria-label="Select Value"
        (selectionChange)="onOptionValueSelectionChanged($event)" formControlName="value" class="example-margin"
        [(ngModel)]="element.Value" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let s of valueArr" [value]="s">
          <span *ngIf="!s">
          </span>
          <span *ngIf="s">
            {{s}}
          </span>
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Action section -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index" class="action-link">
      <a (click)="openDialog('Delete',i)" class="btn btn-md btn-danger text-upper" style="cursor: pointer;"
        *ngIf="i !== 0">Delete</a>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</mat-table>


</div>
```

add.component.ts:

```
    option: any =[
            "Size",
            "Colour"
          ]

          size: any = [
            "28",
            "30",
            "32",
            "34",
            "36",
            "38",
            "40",
            "42",
            "44"
          ]

          color: any =[
            "Black",
            "Grey",
            "White",
            "Blue",
            "Red",
            "Pink",
            "Navy blue"
          ]

          valueArr: any =[];
displayedColumns: string[] = ['Name', 'value', 'action'];

  dataSource: any[] = [
    {Name: '', Value: ''}
  ]
        onOptionTypeSelectionChanged(event: any){
            console.log('value', event);
            if (event.value=='Size') {
              this.valueArr = this.size;
            }else{
              this.valueArr = this.color;
            }
          }
    openDialog(action,index) {

        if(action == 'Add'){
          this.dataSource = this.dataSource.concat([{Name: [''], Value: ['']}]);
          //console.log('data',this.dataSource);
          //this.table.renderRows();
        }else if(action == 'Delete'){
          //this.dataSource.splice(index, 1);
          this.dataSource = this.dataSource.filter((value,key)=>{
            return key != index;
          });
        }
      }
```

By click on add button I am creating the new row with drop down box. But here my issue is as second drop down is depend on first drop down value then when I am selecting any value from 1st drop down the related values are populating for second drop down present in each row which is wrong.

I need if user selected the 1st row 1st drop down values accordingly the 1st row second dropdown values will populate not others.

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz repro?

Comment: This is off-topic, based on the standard guidelines of Unclear or Missing [mcve].